Gradle Build Fails with "Unsupported class file major version 65" After Updating to Java 17
I’m working on a Flutter project and recently updated to Java 17. Since the update, my build fails with the following error when trying to run assembleDebug:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not open cp_settings generic class cache for settings file '.../android/settings.gradle'.


BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'BuildScript' Unsupported class file major version 65

It seems to be related to Gradle and Java compatibility. I’ve already tried updating the gradle-wrapper.properties to a Gradle version that supports Java 17, but the error persists. Here's what I’ve done so far:
Updated gradle-wrapper.properties to use Gradle version 7.3.3:
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip
Ensured Java 17 is installed and set as the default JAVA_HOME on my system.
Flutter doctor output confirms that Flutter is using Java 17.
Despite these steps, the build continues to fail. Here's the full error output:

BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'BuildScript' Unsupported class file major version 65

Steps I’ve Tried:
Updating Gradle to 7.3.3 in gradle-wrapper.properties.
Running flutter clean and rebuilding the project.
Ensuring JAVA_HOME is pointing to the correct Java 17 installation.
Environment:
Flutter version: (specific version)
Java version: 17
Gradle version: 7.3.3 (set in gradle-wrapper.properties)
This is my build.gradle code
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '17'
}    

P.S. All of this started when i updated Android Studio to the Ladybug version

Ladybug uses by default the included Java 21 version (class file version 65), in Koala it was Java 17. I think you have to manually change the Gradle JDK version in Android Studio back to 17.

@Robert there is no setting on Ladybug that allows you to change jdk versions for gradle

You mean you have not found it yet. https://stackoverflow.com/a/79049864/150978

I found the solution to the problem, I followed @Robert advice. All I needed to do was to configure flutter to use my old java 17 directory
flutter config --jdk-dir <path-to-java-sdk-17-home-directory>

after I did that command everything worked.

For me, instead of trying to install or look for older gradle which doesn't exist on my machine. I look for the gradle definition on my newly created Flutter project and copy back to my older project.
Create a new flutter project and look for distributionUrl in /android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.10.2-all.zip

Copy and paste back to your older project's

    // TODO: Remove this when flutter Updates
    // ndkVersion: flutter.ndkVersion
    ndkVersion "25.1.8937393"
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '19'
    }


I ran into this issue, but didn't have the old java 17 version around (fresh install of an OS, restoring my Flutter app from a backup).
To fix, I had to download and use Android Studio Koala, which still includes Java 17, and use that to run AGP Upgrade Assistant. That let me slowly walk my old Gradle version from 7.1.2 -> 7.4.2, and then again from 7.4.2 -> 8.6.1.

Using Flutter 3.27.1 and Android Studio LadyBug 2024.2.1 Patch 3, the solution I found was to mainly update the distributionUrl to 8.3-all; set com.android.application to version 8.1.0 or higher; and set coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled to true for dependencies that require it:
../android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists 
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip

../android/settings.gradle
//..
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    // Note that I use 8.2.1 to meet some of the dependencies I use. 
    // So if you're still getting an error, try 8.2.1:  
    id "com.android.application" version "8.1.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.22" apply false
}

../android/app/build.gradle
android {
    namespace = "com.example.app"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        // Note that some of your dependencies may require desugaring. 
        // Add the following line if so:
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true // may be required
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // ..
        minSdk = flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutter.versionCode
        versionName = flutter.versionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // ..
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Include this if you set coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled to true:
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.2'
}

